# Creating RDD using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to create a `RDD[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)]`. Can I use tuple, `String` and a `DateTime` value and create it within a method instead of reading it from a text file?

I am using Scala to create this, Can anybody please help me?

Actually I wanted to create  RDD[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)]  using the below method.

```
def getRDDForPersistance(sparkContext: SparkContext): RDD[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)] = {
    var stringTouple = ("organization_name", "product_name", "resource_id")
    var resourceName = "test_resource_name"
    val date: DateTime = DateTime.now()
    var rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(stringTouple, resourceName, date))
```

But it doesn't let me to return the created RDD. It seems like I am not returning the RDD that the method is expecting to return. So how can I create the RDD[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)]. Please help me....
    return rdd
  }

Comment: Could you add the code that you are having trouble with? With so few information it's not possible to help.

Comment: @Anushka Here you have examples http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/zhe/ZhenHeSparkRDDAPIExamples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error when you try to pass parameters withing Seq. Please try the below code.

```
def getRDDForPersistanceX(sparkContext: SparkContext): RDD[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)] = {
    var stringTouple = ("organization_name", "product_name", "resource_id")
    var resourceName = "test_resource_name"
    val date: DateTime = DateTime.now()
    var rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((stringTouple, resourceName, date)))
return rdd
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like:

```
val myStruct: List[((String, String, String), String, DateTime)] = ...
val myRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(myStruct)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to initialize the first line in your answer.  Thanks